# Yii2 How to filter user list by account wise

Tags: filter, yii2, roles, webvimark

I have installed this module (webvimark/user-management) for managing users and roles. 
I have the table like user_account fields are userid, accountid, Here I want to filter the users list by account wise, Currently it showing all users to all accounts i want to restrict users by account wise.

Comment: what do you mean for "account wise"... ?  show code sample

Comment: In my application, There is a multiple account like each customer have one account

Account 1, Account 2, Account 3 and etc. Each account have the multiple type of users (admin, manager, user), 
Superadmin have the over all control of users, admin should be each account control, But I could not list users of by admin separately in this plugin instead of its listing all the users into admin